# Shading lines on corners of extruded faces on cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am a beginner in Blender and 3D modelling in general. I have 'pushed' inside a few faces of a subdivided cylinder mesh, which has a bevel modifer active in the stack, but I get diagonal shading lines on corners of the cut as shown in the screenshot. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've created bevels around your hole, so it makes ngons on this part of your cylinder. You will have almost no pinching with this solution:

[image]

[image]